# Resource variables in TensorFlow for microcontrollers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

While going through the "Hello world" example for TFLM I noticed that when the interpreter is initialized, a constant number of resource variables is set. I couldn't find any documentation about this. Could someone explain why are these used here, and how this "24" value is estimated?

```
constexpr int kTensorArenaSize = 3000;
uint8_t tensor_arena[kTensorArenaSize];

constexpr int kNumResourceVariables = 24;

tflite::RecordingMicroAllocator* allocator(
tflite::RecordingMicroAllocator::Create(tensor_arena, kTensorArenaSize));
tflite::RecordingMicroInterpreter interpreter(
  tflite::GetModel(g_hello_world_float_model_data), op_resolver, allocator,
  tflite::MicroResourceVariables::Create(allocator, kNumResourceVariables),
  &profiler);
```